# I did changes on the pod in k8s how can I export the pod and apply to deployment

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I created a deployment yaml file then applied it. I executed:

```
   ‘kubectl exec -it POD bin/bash’
```

Inside the container, I did apt install for manythings.
Now if I applied the deployment again, I will loose all the changes that I did on the pod. How can I reflect the changes that I did on the pod to the deployment? And if I deleted a pod, how would a new one would be created with the same previous pod?

Comment: Please provide some minimal reproducible code so we can work through your problem- and provide some more clarity for ‘manythings’.          thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The persistent solution would be to create a new Dockerfile for your image or extend your existing Dockerfile with the commands that you executed. Each command could be inserted into your Dockerfile with a `RUN` statement. You could also combine the commands into a single `RUN` statement, if possible.
To find your executed commands, you can use the `history` command

Comment: I did this, now am facing another error, when I created the deployment, the pod status is: ImagePullBackOff. Something to keep in mind, that the docker file is run successfully with no issues.

Comment: `ImagePullBackOff` means that kubernetes can't find your image. To debug this error, please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848422/how-to-debug-imagepullbackoff)

Comment: If this answer answers your question, please set it as the accepted answer.