# kubectl get pods command shows "ErrImageNeverPull"

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-container-registry

I have uploaded my image on ACR. When I try to deploy it using a `deployment.yaml` with `kubectl` commands, the `kubectl get pods` command shows `ErrImageNeverPull` in the pods.

Also, I am not using minikube. Is it necessary to use minikube for this?
I am a beginner in azure/kubernetes.

I've also used `imagePullPolicy: Never` in the yaml file. It's not working even without this and shows `ImagePullBackOff`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848422/how-to-debug-imagepullbackoff

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  How are you building your image and pushing it to ACR?

Comment: (`ErrImageNeverPull` means you've specified `imagePullPolicy: Never` but the image isn't already on the node.  You can't use it in AKS, or really any environment other than a local-desktop installation.)

Comment: @DavidMaze is right, probably it does not make a lot of sense to use `imagePullPolicy: Never` in an environment like AKS. You may want to read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images). The way forward is likely to set the policy to `IfNotPresent` or `Always`. These pods ending up in `ImagePullBackOff` is another issue. I suggest running `kubectl describe pod` to troubleshoot these, and if needed, ask for help about _that_ issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I got your point that I should not use `imagePullPolicy: Never` because it's for local installation. I'll try running without it and run `kubectl describe pod` for `ImagePullBackOff` issue. Will ask for help if I couldn't solve the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @PayalJindal, any progress?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine. There was a problem with my docker installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Payal Jindal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16077085/payal-jindal) mentioned in the comment:

> It worked fine. There was a problem with my docker installation.

Problem is now resolved. The way forward is to set the image pull policy to `IfNotPresent` or `Always`.

```
spec:
    containers:
        - imagePullPolicy: Always
```